# Looking at how imgur serves its images. How come when I check network tab in Chrome, its sending this PNG and its only 387B?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, google-chrome

I'm looking at

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4JD8.png

[image]

and checked the network tab in chrome, and this is what I see:

[image]

When I look at the response tab for that .png, this is what I see:

[image]

What is that?  How do they send over something like that which is 387B and then render the image in browser?

What can I search for on google so I can set up something like that on my nodeJS api server?

Thanks

Comment: the 304 is the "Nothing changed" header sent back when your browser has a cached image. Clear the cache to see 709729 bytes

Comment: oh ok.  crap.  thanks lol